# Подчеркивание строки таблицы

Tags: html, css

Как на картинке ниже. Нужно сделать чтобы линия была по середине. Пока сделал через border-bottom, возможно ли его как-то позиционировать или нужен другой способ?

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

td.option {
  width: 50%;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="option">Ширина</td>
      <td>40см</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

td.option {
 width: 5%;
}
#dots {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;
  width: 90%;
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="option">Ширина
        <td id="dots"></td>
      </td>
      <td>40см</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Источник: [How to add dotted line after text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43610864/how-to-add-dotted-line-after-text?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

td.option {
  display: flex;
}
td.option:after {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 7px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
  content: '';
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="option">Ширина</td>
      <td>40см</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```